# Cypher: get a list of related nodes from a list of nodes

Tags: list, neo4j, cypher

I have a model like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSW8b.png)
(substations in blue, installations in yellow )

I match paths from certain substations to certain substations.

```
Match (s1:Substation) - [] - (:installation) - [ :feeds1..40 ] - (:installation) - (s2:Substation)
```

This will yields paths existing of a starting substation, 1 or more installations and then a closing substation ( and ofcourse lots of rels in between ) 
But in the output I only want to see all connected Substations.
How do I get that, if only the installations are in my path ???

I tried someting like :

```
with p, filter ( x IN nodes(p) where "ms_installatie" in LABELS(x) ) as installaties,
```

But no good answers here.

At the end I want a CSV output of all Substations 'on' a path ( not 'in', that  would be easy ! )

Any suggestions are welcome.

A simplified output of the suggested query:

```
[[
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV""nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV","nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV","nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"}
]]
```

These are actually 3 paths ( shown when paths (p) are returned, see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUdlW.png) ) . The output I want:

```
[[
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV""nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"}
][
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV","nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"}
][
{"naam":"TILBURG NOORD","nummer":"TBN"},
{"naam":"QUIRIJNSTOK","nummer":"152.6870"},
{"naam":"BP NOORD-OOST TANGEND","nummer":"152.6258"},
{"naam":"VERELST BV","nummer":"152.2020"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"},
{"naam":"L.O.A. A1","nummer":"152.1200A1"}
]]
```

The doubling / tripling of the last station is correct, because this station has 3 installations, whom feed eachother.

Thx.

Comment: So what you want is `s1` and `s2` no ? There is no other `Substation` in the path right ?

Comment: No and Yes, I want s1, then all relates s's to the installations in the path and then s2

Comment: In your picture, there is no path with some`Substation` nodes between two `Substation` nodes (there are only yellow nodes between blue ones).  Otherwise your approach with the filter is the good one. Can you tell why is not worjing with it ?

Comment: My path consist of a blue node, folowed by N yellow nodes and ending with another blue node. My result should consist of all the blue nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but I don't understand. You said a path starts and ends by a blue node and what you want are the blue nodes. So I will come back to my previous comment : what you want is s1 and s2. Can you provide a short example in your question with the result you want.

Comment: I get (see image):
'Edah' - '309956' - '309957' - '309963' - 'Bernhar' (blue, yellow, yellow, yellow, blue ) 
I want :
'Edah' - 'Juliana' - 'Bernhar' (blue, blue, blue)

Comment: so I need the yellows to become their connected blues.
'Edah' for '309956'
'Juliana' for '309957' and
'Bernhar' for '309963' 

and ofcourse many more paths with variable lenghts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of this query (I can't test it on your data), but it should be pretty close :

```
MATCH p=(s1:Substation)-->(:installation)-[:feeds*..40 ]-(:installation)<--(s2:Substation)
WITH s1 AS start, s2 AS end, filter(x IN NODES(p) WHERE "ms_installatie" in LABELS(x) ) as installaties
 UNWIND installaties as node
   MATCH (node)<--(ss:Substation)
   WITH start, end, collect(ss) AS ss_on_path
   RETURN [] + start + ss_on_path + end
```

Comment: very nice. You can leave out the start and end in the return, they will already be in ss_on_path. thx.

Comment: yes but it's avoid to do the second query for the starting and ending nodes :)

Comment: nop you can't ... the start and end allow me to collect nodes for this specific path

Comment: i only ment in the return. so: 
"Return ss_on_path"
is enough

Comment: Hmmmm. Different paths are joined back together. I do get the right substations, but concatenated into 1 array. I need them to be representations of the separate paths.

Comment: WITH st1 AS start, st2 AS end, filter(x IN NODES(p) WHERE 'ms_installatie' in LABELS(x) ) as installaties
 return installaties
still groups the paths. Unwind looses the grouping

Comment: yes the unwind loose the grouping, but with the `WITH start, end, collect(ss)`, I redo the grouping.

Comment: I don't see that happening. E.g. when installaties has 3 groups, nodes has individual objects, The result is 1 list, regrouping isn't done into those 3 groups, but in 1.

Comment: can you update your question with the result of my query ? Like I said, without the data it's hard to see what is going wrong... the only thing I see so far is if you have multiple path between two Substation...